# intercept wordpress add new post with jQuery modal dialog

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have Wordpress custom post types setup with the plugin custom post type UI and added custom fields to the custom post with the advanced custom fields plugin. All is working fine and no problems or whatsoever ...

BUT now my client wants me to setup some sort of reminder on the custom post type submit form, telling the user that some optional custom fields still have the default value.

The user can then decide to stop the form submit and edit the custom fields or decide to do it later and just submit the form now.

I decided for some `jQuery` form submit intercept with `jQuery` modal dialog. first thing I need is to add the `jQuery` functions via `wordpress` hook once you add a new custom post or edit an existing one. here's the code to do that:

```
function mps_enqueue($hook) {
    global $post_type;

    if ( $post_type != "sis-ambulant") return;
    if ( 'post.php' == $hook || 'post-new.php' == $hook ) {

        wp_enqueue_script( 'mps_custom_script', MPS_SCRIPT_URL . '/js/functions.js', array( 'jquery-ui-dialog' ) );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-theme-mps', MPS_SCRIPT_URL . '/css/jquery-ui.min.css');
    }
}
 add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'mps_enqueue' );
```

I then also need some HTML markup which is going to be used by the jQuery modal dialog. I add that markup via another wordpress admin footer action:

```
function my_post_edit_page_footer(){
    global $post_type;
    if ( $post_type != "sis-ambulant") return;
?>
<div id="sis-dialog" title="SIS-Formular Message">
<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 0 0;"></span><?php _e('Some notes for the user', 'mps2015-theme'); ?>:</p>
<p id="sis-dialog-notes"><br /></p>
</div>
<?php
}
add_action( 'admin_footer-post-new.php', 'my_post_edit_page_footer' );   
add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php', 'my_post_edit_page_footer' );
```

Then comes the jQuery code. here I first fill up to variables named `sisgroups` & `sisrequired` with their values. `sisgroups` are the custom fields with the optional values, which I want to alert to the user on the form submit. `sisrequired` is filled up with the required form fields, as iI only want to fire the modal dialog once all required form fields are filled in.

On the form submit I then first check if all required fields are filled in, then I check for the default optional values on the var `sisgroups` and append a note to `#sis-dialog-notes` to inform the user about the default value field and finally fire the jQuery dialog `#sis-dialog`

**Here's the jQuery code:**

```
var sisgroups = []; // here we add our objects to the array so we can later notify on jquery dialog
var sisrequired = []; // here we add all our required fields, so we can only do the jquery dialog reminder after all required fields are filled in

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    a = 0;

    // fill sisgroups with optional radio boxes
    $("div[id*='_thema_']").each(function() {

        sisgroups[a] = {}; // this creates an object - [] creates an array
        sisgroups[a]["key"] = $(this).attr("data-field_key");
        sisgroups[a]["name"] = $(this).attr("data-field_name");

        a++;

    }); // end each _thema_

    r = 0;

    // fill sisrequired with required form fields
    $("div.required").each(function() {

        sisrequired[r] = {};
        sisrequired[r]["key"] = $(this).attr("data-field_key");
        sisrequired[r]["type"] = $(this).attr("data-field_type");
        sisrequired[r]["name"] = $(this).attr("data-field_name");

        r++;
    }); // end each div.required


    $('#sis-dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            "SIS-Formular abschicken": function() {
                $form = $('form#post');
                $form.addClass('values-confirmed');
                $(this).dialog("destroy");
                $form.submit();
                //document.post.submit();
                //document.getElementById("post").submit();
                //$( "#post" ).submit();
                //$(this).dialog().find('form').submit();
                //$('form#post').submit();
            },
            "Bearbeitung fortsetzen": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });


     $('form#post').submit(function(e){

        sisallrequired = true;

        $.each(sisrequired, function(k, v) {

            // we need to check on different types as they are handled differently

            if ( v['type'] == "textarea" || v['type'] == "text" ) {

                if( $("#acf-field-"+v['name']).val().length === 0 ) {
                    sisallrequired = false;
                    return false;
                }
            } else if ( v['type'] == "date_picker" ) {
                if($("input[name='fields["+v['key']+"]']").val().length === 0 ) {
                    sisallrequired = false;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

        // let's add a line break to the sis dialog notes paragraph
        //$("p#sis-dialog-notes").html('<p>&nbsp;</p>');

        // only if all required fields are filled in we do a check on the sisgroups and alert the user via jquery pop-up dialog
        if ( sisallrequired == true ) {

            // sisgroups is an indexed array of object with properties key, name
            $.each(sisgroups, function(key, val) {

                if ($("input[name='fields["+val['key']+"]']:checked").val() == 2 ) {

                    //console.log( $("label[for='acf-field-"+val['name']+"']").text() );

                    $('p#sis-dialog-notes').append( $("label[for='acf-field-"+val['name']+"']").text() + '<br />');
                } else {
                    //console.log("NO VAL OF 2");
                }


            }); // end each sisgroups

            if (!$(this).hasClass('values-confirmed')) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#sis-dialog').dialog('open');
                //valuesCheck();
            }
        } // end if check for filled in fields
    }); // end post.submit
});
```

And actually all is working really well. on the form submit the jQuery does it's thing and I get notified about the default optional custom fields. I hit `submit / publish` and the custom post type gets created BUT it always has the status of `DRAFT` and actually never gets `PUBLISHED`!

And this is exactly my problem! the custom post gets submitted and added (as a draft!) but NEVER gets published! If I remove the jQuery modal dialog code all works fine and the custom post gets published.

so .. what is the problem with the code? been looking for hours and hours and I'm more than desperate to find an answer ;-)

thanks for all your help & looking forward to your replies!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems that i have to answer my own question ;-) but first a BIG THANK YOU goes to Casey Patrick Driscoll over at facebook who guided me towards the problem and the solution.

The actual problem was that the post submit form had multiple submit buttons and calling $form.submit() in the jQuery dialog simply used the first button found in the form which saved the post as a draft.

The first solution would then be to use a click event on the publish button instead of the $('form#post').submit(function(e){});

```
$('#publish').click(function(e){

   // do validation actions here
   if (!$(this).hasClass('values-confirmed')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#sis-dialog').dialog('open');
   }
});
```

do my validation, prevent the default click action and and then on the jQuery modal dialog continue with the #publish click ...

```
        $('#sis-dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            "SIS-Formular abschicken": function() {
                $('#publish').addClass('values-confirmed');
                $(this).dialog("destroy");
                $('#publish').click();
                return true;
            },
            "Bearbeitung fortsetzen": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

which would then finally submit the form with the proper #publish button clicked -> problem solved ;-)

another possiblity would be to still use the $('form#post').submit() event but also observe which form button was clicked

```
var formbuttonclicked = "";

$('form#post input[type="submit"]').click(function(event) {
    formbuttonclicked = event.target.id;
});
```

this click event on the form buttons would observe which button has been clicked. and then on the form submit event we do the usual:

```
    $('form#post').submit(function(e){

   // do validation actions here
   if (!$(this).hasClass('values-confirmed')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#sis-dialog').dialog('open');
   }
});
```

and then on the jQuery modal dialog

```
        $('#sis-dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            "SIS-Formular abschicken": function() {

                $form = $('form#post');
                $form.addClass('values-confirmed');
                $(this).dialog("destroy");
                $('#' + formbuttonclicked).click();
                return true;
            },
            "Bearbeitung fortsetzen": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

we DO NOT submit the form but call the click event on the button which has been stored in the variable formbuttonclicked

```
$('#' + formbuttonclicked).click();
```

problem solved ;-) Thanks again to Casey Patrick Driscoll over at facebook who gave me a bit of his time and the proper insights!

greetings to all
becki